# Not able to interpret decision tree when using class_weights

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I'm working with an imbalanced dataset. I'm using a decision tree (scikit-learn)  to build a model. 
For explaining my problem I've taken iris dataset.
When I'm setting **class_weight=None**, I understood how the tree is assigning the probability scores when I use predict_proba. 
When I'm setting **class_weight='balanced'**, I know its using target value to calculate class weights but I'm not able to understand how the tree is assigning the probability scores.

```
import sklearn.datasets as datasets
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from sklearn.externals.six import StringIO  
from IPython.display import Image  
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
import pydotplus

iris=datasets.load_iris()
df=pd.DataFrame(iris.data, columns=iris.feature_names)
y=iris.target

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=1)

# class_weight=None
dtree=DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=2)
dtree.fit(X_train,y_train)

dot_data = StringIO()
export_graphviz(dtree, out_file=dot_data, filled=True, rounded=True, special_characters=True, feature_names=X_train.columns)
graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())  
Image(graph.create_png()) # I use jupyter-notebook for visualizing the image
```

[image: tree when class_weight=None]

```
# printing unique probabilities in each class
probas = dtree.predict_proba(X_train)
print(np.unique(probas[:,0]))
print(np.unique(probas[:,1]))
print(np.unique(probas[:,2]))

# ratio for calculating probabilities
print(0/33, 0/34, 33/33)
print(0/33, 1/34, 30/33)
print(0/33, 3/33, 33/34)
```

The probabilities assigned by the tree and my ratios (determined by looking at tree image) are matching.

When I use the option **class_weights='balanced'**. I get the below tree.

```
# class_weight='balanced' 
dtree_balanced=DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=2, class_weight='balanced')
dtree_balanced.fit(X_train,y_train)

dot_data = StringIO()
export_graphviz(dtree_balanced, out_file=dot_data,filled=True, rounded=True, special_characters=True, feature_names=X_train.columns)
graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())  
Image(graph.create_png())
```

[image: tree when class_weight='balanced']

I'm printing unique probabilities using below code

```
probas = dtree_balanced.predict_proba(X_train)
print(np.unique(probas[:,0]))
print(np.unique(probas[:,1]))
print(np.unique(probas[:,2]))
```

I'm not able to understand (come-up with a formula) how the tree is assigning these probabilities.